# XMLHttpRequest error on HTTP POST (POST work, return fail)

Tags: c#, flutter, xmlhttprequest, rest

I have a problem with Http Response when I post (on button click) in my app.

The post works, I'm able to follow the request in my C# REST API, and I return an `HttpResponse.OK` with an object Session containing a token property.

Everything is also fine with Fiddler (HTTP 200):

[image]

Button code :

```
Widget _submitButton() {
  return InkWell(
    onTap: () async {
      try {
        var url = Uri.http('localhost:63734', '/api/v1/accounts/login');

        var body = {
            'email': _emailController.text,
            'password': _passwordController.text,
          };
            
 ====>  Response response = await post(url, body: body);

        if (response.statusCode == 200) {
          ...
        }
      }
      on Exception catch(e){
        print(e);
      }
    }
```

It always fall in the Exception catch with the error : `XMLHttpRequest error.`

If I remove the `try-catch`, the stack trace looks comething like :

```
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 155:18                                        handleValue
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 707:44                                        handleValueCallback
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 736:13                                        _propagateToListeners
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 533:7                                         [_complete]
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/async/stream_pipe.dart 61:11                                         _cancelAndValue
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/async/stream.dart 1219:7                                             <fn>
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/operations.dart 324:14  _checkAndCall
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/operations.dart 329:39  dcall
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/html/dart2js/html_dart2js.dart 37307:58                              <fn>
at Object.createErrorWithStack (http://localhost:53362/dart_sdk.js:5054:12)
at Object._rethrow (http://localhost:53362/dart_sdk.js:37670:16)
at async._AsyncCallbackEntry.new.callback (http://localhost:53362/dart_sdk.js:37666:13)
at Object._microtaskLoop (http://localhost:53362/dart_sdk.js:37526:13)
at _startMicrotaskLoop (http://localhost:53362/dart_sdk.js:37532:13)
at http://localhost:53362/dart_sdk.js:33303:9
```

Comment: await post(url, body: body); Should not this be await http.post(url, body: body);?

Comment: @Ritesh it depend how you import `import 'package:http/http.dart';`. In this case, no needs to put http before. It works, I hit my REST endpoint, but the return falls into catch exception...

Comment: Can you please post the exception that you are getting?

Comment: @Ritesh the Exception is only `XMLHttpRequest error`. But I've removed the try-catch, I paste the stack trace at the end of my post.

Comment: may be your are missing some headers, what headers do you see in fiddler for this request?